# Fast way to sort lists in Python so that their corresponding index is at a similar time stamp?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with the same number of elements, but the time stamps fluctuate and are not matched with the same element of the other lists. Is there a way to organize the lists so that the elements correspond with their same index from the other list?
Right now I have

```
sorted1 = []
sorted2 = []
for i in list1:
    for x in list2:
        if (i-1 <= x <= i+1):
            sorted1.append(i)
            sorted2.append(x)
            break
```

This works, but runs extremely slow.

My lists are epoch times that need to be paired.

```
[1412121504, 1412121512, 1412121516, 1412121520, 1412121525, 1412121580]
[1412121470, 1412121515, 1412121525, 1412121560, 1412121580, 1412121600]
```

If they do not have a corresponding time in the other list that is within 1 second either way, I do not want to include them. I would want it to look like this,

```
[1412121516, 1412121525]
[1412121515, 1412121525]
```

Thank you for even reading all this.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? What are you working with. Explaining the data is not as useful as a visual aid and your example confuses me. If you could provide the two lists as they are and how you expect them to be they we can help. Additionally I think you are asking on the wrong site. [codereview.se] might be the site to ask this question as you are looking at optimisation/best practice not fixing an error

Comment: Are `i` and `x` numerical values in the list. Because then  `if(i-1 <= x <= i+1)` does not make sense. You can just directly write `i==x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain two counters to the lists after sorting them, then move them along while comparing the elements:

```py
list1 = [1412121504, 1412121512, 1412121516, 1412121520, 1412121525, 1412121580]
list2 = [1412121470, 1412121515, 1412121525, 1412121560, 1412121580, 1412121600]
# sort the lists
list1.sort()
list2.sort()
# maintain two counters to each of the lists
list1i = 0
list2i = 0
paired1 = []
paired2 = []
while list1i < len(list1) and list2i < len(list2):
    cur1 = list1[list1i]
    cur2 = list2[list2i]
    # too small, advance the first list counter
    if cur1 < cur2 - 1:
        list1i += 1
    # too large, advance the second list counter
    elif cur1 > cur2 + 1:
        list2i += 1
    # we found a pair, increment both to avoid duplicates
    else:
        paired1.append(cur1)
        paired2.append(cur2)
        list1i += 1
        list2i += 1

print(paired1, paired2)
```